# Contextual Windows Roaming User Profiles

Tags: windows, active-directory, roaming-profile

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement a solution so that a user has multiple different roaming user profiles.

Which roaming user profile it uses depends on which OU the current computer is in.

So when I log into computer 1, 3, or 5 (In the "Odd" OU) I have one roaming user profile.

And when I log into computer 2, 4, or 6 (In the "Even" OU) I have a second roaming user profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roaming profile path is a User Group Policy setting. You want it to be based on the computer OU.

Question: How do you apply User Group Policy based on the computer OU?

Answer: Loopback processing!